# Removing outlines from features using arcpy GraduatedColorsRenderer in python

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

ArcGIS Pro 2.8.8 Python 3.7 with arcpy 2.8 Standard arcpy (no addons).
Using Python and arcpy I am trying to style a layer after running a process on it so that it is using graduated colours with no outlines around the features. I have been over the Esri Documentation and help but cannot find a solution. There was a solution implemented using slayer.symbology.outlineColor = {'RGB' : [0, 0, 0, 0]} but when I added it nothing happened, not even an error message.

```
aprx = apArcGISProject('current')
map = aprx.listMaps('Map')[0]
slayer = map.listLayers('GRID')[0]
query = 'vals > 0'
slayer.definitionQuery = query
style = slayer.symbology

style.updateRenderer('GraduatedColorsRenderer')
style.renderer.classificationField = 'vals'
style.renderer.breakCount = 5
style.renderer.classificationMethod = 'Quantile'
style.renderer.colorRamp = aprx.listColorRamps('Yellow to Red')[0]

slayer.symbology = style
slayer.symbology.outlineColor = {'RGB' : [0, 0, 0, 0]}
layout = aprx.listLayouts(user4)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/classbreak-class.htm by entering into the classBreaks class you can loop over each break and alter attributes there. This is where the outlineWidth and outlineColor are capable of being edited in the GraduatedColoursRenderer renderer type. Note the for loop just after the style.renderer.colorRamp = aprx.listColorRamps('Yellow to Red')[0] line...

```
aprx = apArcGISProject('current')
map = aprx.listMaps('Map')[0]
slayer = map.listLayers('GRID')[0]
query = 'vals > 0'
slayer.definitionQuery = query
style = slayer.symbology

style.updateRenderer('GraduatedColorsRenderer')
style.renderer.classificationField = 'vals'
style.renderer.breakCount = 5
style.renderer.classificationMethod = 'Quantile'
style.renderer.colorRamp = aprx.listColorRamps('Yellow to Red')[0]
for brk in style.renderer.classBreaks:
    brk.symbol.outlineColor = {'RGB' : [0,0,0,0]} # Changes the Outline Colour
    brk.symbol.outlineWidth = 0 # Changes the Outline Width

slayer.symbology = style
slayer.symbology.outlineColor = {'RGB' : [0, 0, 0, 0]}
layout = aprx.listLayouts(user4)[0]
```